# Form not found, but ID and name are correct?

Tags: google-apps-script

I a google form with the correct form ID and name added to this apps script:

[image]

```
    function openForm() {
      var form = findFormByName('Comments');
      if (form) {
        populateQuestions(form);
      } else { 
        Logger.log('Form not found');
      }
    }

    function findFormByName(formName) {
      var forms = FormApp.openById('1s0rjQIRY2i8CZsoxlu--TBR7q4b3wHxBslItWOMrc1s').getItems(FormApp.ItemType.FORM);
      for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        var form = forms[i].asForm();
        if (form.getTitle() === formName) {
          return form;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    function populateQuestions(form) {
      var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
      var itemsArray = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);

      if (googleSheetsQuestions.length > 0) {
        var choiceArrayA = removeDuplicates(googleSheetsQuestions.map(function(row) {
          return row[0] ? String(row[0]).trim() : '';
        }));
        if (itemsArray.length > 0) {
          var question1 = itemsArray[0].asListItem();
          question1.setChoiceValues(choiceArrayA);
        }
      }
    }

    function removeDuplicates(array) {
      return array.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
    }

    function getQuestionValues() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1OK0EIoGRD8RdQ4gOeCqy6ycT5Y-MvLZYXBvQo2MpJpI');
      var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data');
      var returnData = questionSheet.getRange(2, 1, questionSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
      return returnData;
    }
```

any clue what im doing wrong? I added in the rest of the code pertaining to the other functions the first two blocks of code are referencing.

edit: picture to show me implementing a solution to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that empowers us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Cooper hey, thanks for responding. So I realized the name had a ")" character in the form name, but I took that out and still getting same error. these two functions should be straight forward: find form name and form ID, but its not

Comment: @Cooper so this script works perfectly on another google account, but when I recreated it with my work google account, it doesn't find form name

Comment: But my point is that you have provided us with an example that we cannot run because there are undefined functions i.e. `populateQuestions`

Comment: @Cooper hey, good call. I updated the code in my post to reference the other relevant functions

Comment: Another possibility is that since you are using an onOpen which is a simple trigger and simple triggers cannot perform operations that require permission so you might wish to try creating an installable onOpen trigger.

Comment: Just to make sure I got your error here as it is not clearly stated on the post. Your code is not pushing through the first code right? If this is the case I am trying to make sense of this part function openForm() {
      var form = findFormByName('Comments');
      if (form) {
        populateQuestions(form);
      } else { 
        Logger.log('Form not found'); as this return a null value, what are you trying to accomplish in that part?

Comment: @Babanana I am trying to find the form name "Comments" in that block. What I am trying to achieve in this code block in my post is find that form name, form ID and then reference a google sheet ID and take column A values to populate in the first form question dropdown

Comment: @Babanana it is not pushing through the first code block, correct

Comment: Moreover, there is only 1 title for a form. To get that all you need is getTitle like this var forms = FormApp.openById('YouFormId').getTitle(); I do apologize that I get confuse of you expected results from this.

Comment: @Babanana I updated the first block:

    function openForm() {

      var form = FormApp.openById('1s0rjQIRY2i8CZsoxlu--TBR7q4b3wHxBslItWOMrc1s').getTitle()

      if (form) {

        populateQuestions(form);

      } else { 

        Logger.log('Form not found');
      }

    }


and still getting a form not found error. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Getting Form Title

What's happening with your code is that you are trying to get the Question type and compare it with your supposed Form Title. I created a fix with your form title part of code.

### Sample Code:

```
function openForm() {
  var form = findFormByName('Comments');
   if (form) { populateQuestions(form); }
  else { Logger.log(form); }
}

function findFormByName(formName) {
  var forms = FormApp.openById('1B6gBnmAcxvRo-KYtLQOqPgOWaphXNDJ-YWHyqVh893k');
  var formTitle = forms.getTitle();
  
  if (formTitle === formName) {
    return forms;
  }
  else {
    return null
  }
}
```

### Reference:

[getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#gettitle)

Comment: Please feel free to comment how this solution worked out for you.

Comment: I am still getting a form not found error

Comment: im starting to think it may be a permissions thing. I already went through the google authentication process when I set up the trigger for populate questions

Comment: Can you screenshot you exact error please? This code is working for me for testing I may not be seeing the whole picture in this.

Comment: I tried logging the title of the Form and it seems that it is returning blank. Can you try to do a new copy of a for and then get that ID instead just to cover all bases here?

Comment: picture uploaded at bottom of screen. Am I able to maybe share a link with you to the form to troubleshoot?

Comment: Thank you for trying weirdly enough it did work on mine I just made a copy of the form. Deleted the Original Form Title and Retyped it and Pressed Enter,

Comment: this is so hard to figure out, I copied it and allowed the permissioned in the advanced settings popup. Any reason why this would work for my personal google account but not for one I set up that multiple people have access to the password?

Comment: Just to clarify our recent changes to your code made it work on your Personal Google Account?  I don't have full oversight on your project so I cannot say for sure but it might be coming from permission side of things, whoever runs the codes must have access to all documents involve in your current set up. I want to also understand what you mean on multiple people have access to the password, what type of account are you referring with this?

Comment: So I am one of 5 people who have the password to a google account we use for work. I have full permissions for editor for every document on the account

Comment: In reference to the code, my original code thats in the post worked on my personal google account. form was found with no issue. once I copied and pasted the code and updated to the form name and form ID in the google account where we all share the password, it didnt work anymore

Comment: Again, I execute the second block findFormByName and it executes properly, but it doesn't execute openForm because it says form not found

Comment: I will do some testing, I can see that your old form was in the trash. Can you provide the new form you are using for testing?

Comment: Hey I figured it out with a diff script, thank you for your help!